# How do you search for all the locked questions

Tags: support, search

A lot of the locked questions in SO that I have seen have been really cool to explore and have a great time laughing and having fun. Apparently, I can't find a way to search for a list of all the locked questions.

Is there anyway to search for only locked questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a search-help when you did a search, which links to the help-page listing everything: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching.
That lists, among others, also the operator for choosing only (not) locked questions.

> locked:1